I am making some honest comments so that you might/would benefit from what I am saying. - difference in meaning?
Example 1

I am making some honest comments so that you would benefit from what I am saying.

Example 2

I am making some honest comments so that you might benefit from what I am saying.

Do they mean the same?
Does "would" means uncertainty here as "might" does?
My understanding is that "would" here actually implies a second conditional.

I wouldn't bother with either highlighted verb (or alternative auxiliaries such as can, will, may,...), or the relativizer that. Or the reference back to what I am saying. They're all just pointless verbiage that adds nothing to the meaning. Just say I am making some honest comments so you benefit from them. As opposed to I am making some honest comments because I like to say what I think, or whatever.

Idiomatically, I suggest I'm being [brutally] honest for your benefit is more natural for native Anglophones. The implication is the speaker might have preferred not to be honest, because "conventional polite white lies" are less rude / stressful / confrontational. But for the benefit of the addressee, the speaker is prepared to do something he'd rather not do.

Your first sentence is wrong.
"Would" is used with the conditional:

If I made honest comments you would benefit from what I was saying.

The correct version of what you meant to say is:

I am making some honest comments so that you will benefit from what I am saying.

This implies a certainty - that it is unquestionable that you will benefit.
The second version allows for some doubt, that even though I have made the honest comments you will not necessarily benefit from them. It can be also used in the case of certainty.

Right, simple, clear and concise. +1

Similarly "so that you may benefit" (in the future).

Yes. "Would" could make sense if you added some condition. Like, "... that if you listened to them you would benefit". But as the sentence is given, there is no condition for "would" to apply to.

might is also OK.  The comments are there for you to take advantage of. There's nothing holding you back.  might expresses possibility without obstacle. It's up to you to take advantage of them, or not.
